# How do I get a Save As… option always appear in my Apple apps without using the OPTION key?

Tags: macos

I couldn’t find an answer here, so maybe this doesn’t bug anyone else. But surely it must?

Basically, when using Apple apps such as TextEdit, Preview, Pages, Numbers, there is no Save As… option unless you hold down the OPTION key. This is just such a time waster and can’t possibly ‘add’ to the user experience. Plain dumb if you ask me.

How can I add this option so that it appears by default **without** having to press the OPTION key?

Comment: what they gave works fine for me - "duplicate" - magic...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, but duplicate is basically an extra step. I've never duplicated something and then not just saved to rename. And then had to close the original. Which is the same thing "save as" in many more steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest workaround is to actually create a *custom* shortcut for Save As… using the same keyboard shortcut as the Duplicate option. In other words, **don’t use the default keyboard shortcut** of <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, but change it to <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> instead.

You can do this as follows:

1. Go to **Apple > System Preferences…**
2. Click on the **Keyboard** preference pane
3. Select the **Shortcuts** tab
4. In the lefthand pane select the **App Shortcuts** option
5. Now click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button
6. Ensure that *All Applications* is selected for the Application field
7. For the Menu Title field type in “Save As…”
8. Click on the Keyboard Shortcut field and now press the <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> keys (remember, this will totally replace the *Duplicate* option from appearing in the menu).
9. Now click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button

Now you’ll have the Save As… option by default in your various Apple app File menus.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean by going to the menu bar with the mouse...

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>  will make a duplicate & append 'copy' to the name. This can then be saved in the regular manner.

[image]

Alternatively, if you just use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>    <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>  it will go straight to the Save As... dialog.